# Fatal errors when i activvate asta theme on my localhost

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache, xampp

i am using local web host for my website, it work fine but when I active ASTRA theme my whole website crashes by giving this error, this theme works fine on other free webhost but it fail here on localhost what should i do

> : Uncaught ArgumentCountError: array_merge() does not accept unknown named parameters in C:\xampp\htdocs\itsosmos\wp-includes\widgets.php:1265 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\itsosmos\wp-includes\widgets.php(1265): array_merge(wp_inactive_widgets: Array, sidebar-1: Array, header-widget: Array, footer-widget-1: Array, footer-widget-2: Array, advanced-footer-widget-1: Array, advanced-footer-widget-2: Array, advanced-footer-widget-3: Array, advanced-footer-widget-4: Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\itsosmos\wp-includes\widgets.php(1220): retrieve_widgets(true) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\itsosmos\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(289): _wp_sidebars_changed('Twenty Twenty') #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\itsosmos\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\itsosmos\wp-includes\plugin.php(478): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\itsosmos\wp-includes\theme.php(3267): do_action('after_switch_th...', 'Twenty Twenty', Object(WP_Theme)) #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\itsosmos\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(287): check_theme_switched('') #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\itsosmos\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\itsosmos\wp-includes\plugin.php(478): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #9 C:\xampp\htdocs\itsosmos\wp-settings.php(546): do_action('init') #10 C:\xampp\htdocs\itsosmos\wp-config.php(90): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #11 C:\xampp\htdocs\itsosmos\wp-load.php(37): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #12 C:\xampp\htdocs\itsosmos\wp-admin\admin.php(34): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #13 C:\xampp\htdocs\itsosmos\wp-admin\themes.php(10): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #14 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\itsosmos\wp-includes\widgets.php on line 1265strong text

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be PHP 8 problem with your theme. Ask for creator to update theme to compatible with PHP 8, Or downgrade your PHP to lower version.

Comment: I'm glad it was useful.